# mount error(115) w/ Windows 10 share. Error connecting to socket

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I have a Windows 10 share that I need to access from a Ubuntu 16.04.3 machine. I created /media/sharefolder on the ubuntu box, and shared //WINDOWSMACHINE/sharename (with "Everyone" full access permissions, "Everyone" full access security settings).

My /etc/fstab line is this

```
//WINDOWSMACHINE/sharename /media/sharefolder cifs uid=me,credentials=/home/me/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

However, the share does not work:

- sudo mount -a returns "mount error(115): Operation now in progress"
- syslog errors:
  CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
  CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115

Here's what I've tried

- [Why is my machine unable to mount my SMB drives ("CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation", return code -115)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161187/why-is-my-machine-unable-to-mount-my-smb-drives-cifs-vfs-error-connecting-to?newreg=7f1a972662eb454ab5e375d3bd80c153) - disabled windows machine firewall, checked iptables and hosts.deny (default versions)
- smbclient -L 1.2.3.4: Connection to 1.2.3.4 failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT)
- https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-926114-start-0.html - smbtree -b -N: lists all machines on network except the \WINDOWSMACHINE
- ping WINDOWSMACHINE: successful pings with correct IPs (1.2.3.4)

Any help is much appreciated!

**Update:** This configuration used to work fine, until I upgraded from kernel 4.4.0-92 to 4.4.0-93. Not sure if this is incidental or something related to the upgrade.