# Connecting to CIFS Error 115

Tags: mount, vpn, cifs

I'm trying to connect to a data share via the VPN of my university. I have contacted support and set the following:

In my /et/fstab:

```
//serverlocatoin/share /mnt/Ldrive cifs credentials=/home/laurens/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

And double checked the smbcredentials file.

When running `sudo mount -a` the following error is returned:
[image]

My university IT guy simply told me to just revert to using a windows machine.

## What I've tried

- Read the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)
- Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161187/why-is-my-machine-unable-to-mount-my-smb-drives-cifs-vfs-error-connecting-to) post, tried switching off ipv6, did not help
- ping the server, returned 'unknown host'
- Checked if VPN connection is active via `ifconfig -a` The VPN seems to be active.
  [image]
- Tried to approach via chrome browser, returns a 'your file was not found' error, suggesting that the server returns something, right?
  [image]
- Changing the SMB protocol as in the below answer. Rebooted, still error 115.
  [image]

Other post that had the same question but did not have an answer:
[post1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950768/mount-error115-w-windows-10-share-error-connecting-to-socket?noredirect=1&lq=1)

What could be the problem and/or how could I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the windows server are no longer accepting `smbv1`, the original version of the Server Message Block (SMB) protocol. Version 1 is obsolete, as it has well-known shortcomings.
Try adding

```
client min protocol = SMB2  
client max protocol = SMB3
```

in the `global` section of `smb.conf`. Then restart `smbd`.

Your chrome browser test will not work. By typing `file:///something` you are trying to access a file on you local file system, not a web server. Apparently you don't have a file named `/something` like your server on your computer.

Using `ping` you should omit `//` in front of names/ip-addresses
Try `ping serveraddress`, e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding the lines to the smb.conf. Error 115 remains. The pinging without the '//' did yield a return, confirming that I can contact the server.

Comment: What is the output of: 'mount -t cifs //<serverlocation>/share /mnt/Ldrive -o username=<yourusername>'? (Replace <serverlocation> with the correct address and <yourusername> with your actual username on the windows machine. Did this command ask for a password? Does a folder named /mnt/Ldrive exist on your local computer?