# mounting cifs gives error 115 but can ping and smbclient connects

Tags: networking, network-manager, samba, cifs

I have a SMB fileshare that used to connect to a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS workstation but something in the local network config has changed and now I get mount error(115): Operation now in progress error.  This computer has 6x physical network interfaces and uses NetworkManager.  At some point something screwed up with routing and had to fiddle with the Metrics to even be able to ping the file server without also specifying the Network Interface.  That's resolved but ever since getting the error 115.  File share seems fine, can still mount on other Windows and CentOS machines.

I can ping the file share fine and I can connect to it fine using smbclient so it's something on the cifs side.

How can I debug this issue further?

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002358/connecting-to-cifs-error-115

Comment: More information is needed: mount options for the share, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fully gotten to the bottom of this but worked out some causes.  I did a tcpdump of pinging, connecting with smbclient and attempting to mount using cifs.  The root cause is some firewalls (not local on machine) letting ipv6 traffic through but not ipv4.  So when smbclient tries to connect it first tries the resolved v4 a couple of times, then gives up and tries v6 and can connect.  However it looks like cifs just gives up when it can't connect on v4, this would explain the different functionality between the two.  However there's still some weirdness as I still can't mount using the v6 address, but at least now cifs returns error 111 which is permission denied.  Will update if anything else useful comes up.